# dart pub package upload user?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I've recently started using a new development machine and when I try to upload my pub package it fails saying "You aren't an uploader for package '\name\'." I've had a look on the pub site but haven't found away for me to find out A) who it thinks I am and B) how to give my current user access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the package name?

You can take a look at the command `pub uploader` to modify your local uploader settings.

Comment: where is the pub executable though? or is there a console in the dart editor for entering pub commands? the package is called "eventable"

Comment: `pub` is an essential part of the Dart installation. You may miss a path setting to Darts bin directory. pub.dartlang.org doesn't list a result for `eventtable`. I expected you already succeeded at least one time publishing the package. Why could it otherwise complain that you are not the uploader. How did you get the `You aren#t an uploader for package '\name\'.` Did you call `pub publish` from within the DartEditor?

Comment: yeh I published from within dart editor before, if I log on to my laptop now where I originally published it will let me do it, its just annoying that I have to do that. [eventable](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/eventable)

Comment: You are using the same user account on both machines?

Comment: if you don't have pub on your systems path variable you can run it directly from `<dart-install-location>/dart-sdk/bin` then drop in a pubspec.yaml file for the project you want to run against and, my problem was solved with `uploader add <email>`, thanks